# JQuery tabs add dynamically ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui

I am new to JQuery, and have been trying to implement a tabbed interface where the tabs are added dynamically and their contents loaded via Ajax. I am using JQuery-ui tabs. I have been trying to solve this problem for days, and have been googling all around and read all relevant threads here in SO. Right now, the interface works if I add only one tab - the tab is created, it is selected, and its content loaded via Ajax. However, when I add a second tab, its content seem to be properly loaded, but when I select the first tab, I see the contents of second tab appended to the contents of the first tab, then I am no longer able to switch between tabs.

I am working on Rails 3. The code is in Coffeescript, but I think it should be easy to read for any Javascript'er. Here are some notes:

- `$('a.edit')` is my selector to add the tab. To avoid multiple firings, I first check if the selector has already been bound before biding the adding of the tab with the mouse click
- the tab close works well
- the urls and tab name are passed as attributes. The urls point to html forms (via partials in Rails)
- in the generated html, when I add a tab, two ui-tab-panel's are created with ids "ui-tabs-1" and "ui-tabs-2". The tab has an href that points to the second. Only the first has ".ui-tabs-hide".

  - when I add the second tab, I'll have four ui-tab-panel's, with the tabs pointing to "ui-tabs-2" and "ui-tabs-4", but none of them have ".ui-tabs-hide".

Here is the code

```
$(->
        if !($('a.edit').is('.bound'))
            $('a.edit').on('click', ->
                addTab($(this).attr('url'), $(this).attr('tag'))  
            )
            $('a.edit').addClass('bound')
        $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs
        #$tabs.tabs
            closable: true
            cache: true
            tabTemplate: '<li><a href="#{href}">#{label}</a> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close">Remove Tab</span></li>'
            add: (event, ui) ->
                $tabs.tabs('select', '#' + ui.panel.id)

        addTab = (url, tab_name)->
            $tabs.tabs('add',url,tab_name)

        $( "#tabs span.ui-icon-close" ).live(
            "click", ->
                index = $( "li", $tabs ).index( $( this ).parent() )
                $tabs.tabs( "remove", index )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem, I introduced some minor changes. The major one was to add the line `$tabs = $('#tabs')` so all the references and method calls to tab should refer to the selector itself. I am not sure why, but before I had `$tabs = $('#tabs').tabs( ... )`. Another change was one needed in the cases where the selector `$('a.edit')` was added dynamically. Because the selector may not exist when the page is initally loaded, I changed the binding from `.on('click,-> )` to `.live('click', ->)`, and changed the flag so a new '.bounded' class is added to #tabs to prevent multiple firing.

```
$(-> 
    $tabs = $('#tabs')

    if !($tabs.is('.bound')) 
        $('a.edit').live('click', -> 
            addTab($(this).attr('url'), $(this).attr('tag'))   
        ) 
        $tabs.addClass('bound') 

    $tabs.tabs 
        closable: true 
        cache: true 
        tabTemplate: '<li><a href="#{href}">#{label}</a> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close">Remove Tab</span></li>' 
        add: (event, ui) -> 
            $tabs.tabs('select', '#' + ui.panel.id) 

    addTab = (url, tab_name)-> 
        $tabs.tabs('add',url,tab_name) 

    $( "#tabs span.ui-icon-close" ).live( 
        "click", -> 
            index = $( "li", $tabs ).index( $( this ).parent() ) 
            $tabs.tabs( "remove", index ) 
)
```